# Formating numbers in multiindex array Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Admin  ...  Unnamed: 14
Job Family Name                    Values                     ...             
Dentist    McDentistFace, Dentist  UDS Encounters   0.000000  ...     1.000000
                                   Actual FTE       0.000000  ...     1.000000
                                   UDS Encounters2       NaN  ...  1475.000000
                                   Actual FTE2           NaN  ...     7.589426
```

Where the Job Family, Name, and Values are all dimensions of a multiindex.

I'm trying to format the float values in the file, but can't seem to get it to work. I have been able to highlight certain rows with this line:

```
for i in flagged_providers:
ind = flagged_providers.index(i) * 4
for q in i.results.keys():
    style.apply(highlight_col, axis=0, subset=(style.index[ind: ind + 4], q))
    # style.apply(format_numbers, axis=0, subset=(style.index[ind: ind + 2], q))
```

where format_numbers is:

```
def format_numbers(s):
return f'{s:,.2f}'
```

and I have also tried this:

```
for i in flagged_providers:
    format_dict[(i.jfam, i.name)] = '{:.2f}'
    format_dict[(i.jfam, i.name)] = '{:.2f}'
style.format(formatter=format_dict)
```

But I can't quite seem to get it to work. Hoping for any ideas? I want to format the first two rows as percentages, then export to excel using the to_excel function.

Comment: Have you tried something like this:

```pd.options.display.float_format = '{:2f}'.format```

Comment: I did, but the formatting did not carry over when written to excel

Comment: ```.to_csv()``` has a ```float_format``` parameter you can look into. So it'd be ```df.to_csv(..., float_format="%.2f")``` in your case.

Comment: Also, there are other floats that I need to not be formatted like that.

Comment: That wont work either because I have cells I need to highlight which I don't believe is a function that to_csv function does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. Probably a better way to do this but what worked was:

```
style.applymap(lambda x: 'number-format:0.00%;', subset=(style.index[ind: ind + 2], locations))
```